# Books on superconductivity and its relation to spontaneous symmetry breaking

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, superconductivity, symmetry-breaking, higgs

I wish to understand more about the relationship between superconductivity and spontaneous symmetry breaking. I would also appreciate sources for learning about symmetry breaking and particles in more general terms.

My knowledge is mostly from condensed matter, so I am not too familiar with particle physics to begin with. I would also like to learn more about lagrangians, fields, and he reasoning behind them.

My final goal however, is to use the knowledge in a condensed matter setting.

Does anyone have good books/review articles to recommend. I have access to most known journals through my university.

Comment: You might like the textbooks by Altland & Simons and also Wen.

Comment: All books on superconductivity shortly discuss the relation to symmetry breaking. Perhaps you want to know more about the relation to Higgs. In this case, a few references are : http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0503400 and the book by S. Weinberg, The Quantum Theory of Fields (Volume 2) (Cambridge University Press, 1995). Also of interest as a first reading on all the topics you mention : A. Zee, Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell, 1st ed. (Princeton University Press, 2003). And of course, please check Wikipedia and Scholarpedia as well.

Comment: [Weinberg, Steven. "Superconductivity for particular theorists." Progress of theoretical physics. Supplement 86 (1986): 43-53.](http://ci.nii.ac.jp/els/110001208319.pdf?id=ART0001546076&type=pdf&lang=en&host=cinii&order_no=&ppv_type=0&lang_sw=&no=1457399644)