# Literature recommendations for superconductivity

Tags: solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, superconductivity, greens-functions

What text books / review papers give an easy introduction to superconductivity? The literature should be suitable for Master students with some background knowledge in theoretical solid state physics and second quantization.

I do know *Introduction to Superconductivity*  by Michael Tinkham but I find the book not very well written at times.

A plus would be if the text also showed how the greens function formalism can be applied to theories on superconductivity.

Comment: There is a whole chapter about superconductivity in the Piers Coleman "Introduction to Many-Body Physics". Otherwise, there's a chapter in the Bruus "Many-Body Quantum Theory in Condensed Matter Physics: An Introduction"

Comment: Takafumi Kita's book "Statistical Mechanics of Superconductors"?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/194981/2451